# Which Spider-Man movies do I have to watch in order to start watching MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man

I have watched only first Tobey Maguire *Spider-Man* movie and no movies of Spider-Man and MCU other than that.

Comment: Not a dupe, but a helpful link
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/is-there-an-official-marvel-cinematic-universe-viewing-order

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: You could watch *Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Honestly, you don't have to have watched any *Spider-Man* films before watching the MCU. It's a new continuity, and while they don't explain his origin in *[Spider-Man: Homecoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Homecoming)*, all you need to know about Peter in *Captain America: Civil War* is that he wisecracks and throws webs, and that he's younger than most of the rest of the combatants. Otherwise, he can simply be treated as a new combatant who gets some backstory in his following feature film.

Comment: To be clear the only origin story we get is that something happened to Uncle Ben that left May alone caring for Peter and that he was bit by a spider. But we don't see any of this, there are only subtle, and not so subtle, hints (besides the obvious Ben not being there) and we have out of universe interviews.

Comment: I would, however, recommend not starting with the *Avengers* titled films, especially the later ones such as *Infinity War* and *Endgame*, as there are way too many intertwining characters and plot lines to piece together. I suppose you can watch them as straight action flicks, but you are likely to be constantly wondering "why is it odd that this character has returned?" or "why is that artifact important?" at points where the creators assumed you already knew.

Answer (score 7):

#### None, really

The Marvel Cinematic Universe is a contained universe separate from the Raimi trilogy. That said Spider-Man first appears in the MCU in *Captain America: Civil War* and then his solo appearance in *Spider-Man: Homecoming*. We **do not** see Peter's origin story and why he chose to become who he is. It was purposefully left out:

> The truth is, we want audiences to bring their own... let them fill in those blanks right now. They've seen the other films. They've read comics. They can fill that in. That was a very purposeful decision we made to not retread that ground. There are little things that are said here and there that people can read into. What the specific facts are in the past, we don't... we haven't revealed yet.
>
> <sub>[Cinema Blend, The Real Reason Marvel's Spider-Man Movie Doesn't Include Uncle Ben](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1674700/the-real-reason-marvels-spider-man-movie-doesnt-include-uncle-ben-according-to-kevin-feige)</sub>

So it is helpful to know his backstory if you don't already which you can get from the comics or some of the other films. One important distinction between MCU Peter and Raimi Peter though is that his webs are not biological in the MCU.

For what it's worth though I wouldn't watch the MCU Spider-Man films ignoring the rest. The whole Infinity Saga as an overarching plot with lots of character development and references building up one entire story. You would miss a lot and be confused as to what is going on in the background. *Spider-Man: Homecoming* might be fine to watch the majority of out of sequence, though you'd be a little confused as to his mopiness initially. However, *Spider-Man: Far From Home* really has to be watched in sequence because the whole plot is with Peter dealing with the fall out of the previous movies.

These following questions may be of help to you:

- [Is there an official Marvel Cinematic Universe viewing order?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4649/58193)
- [Who is the 'BFP' on Peter's suitcase?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203606/58193)
- [Is there ever any indication in the MCU as to how Spider-Man got his powers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212242/58193)

Answer (score 1):

To *start* watching the MCU, you don't need to watch any Spider-Man movies.

However, assuming you continue to watch the MCU (the power of Disney compels you!), before you get to *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (the 27th movie, although [who's counting?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_On_(franchise))), it's worth watching all of Sony's live-action Spider-Man movies (the [trilogy starring Tobey Maguire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film#Sam_Raimi_films_(2002%E2%80%932007)), and the [two *Amazing Spider-Man* movies starring Andrew Garfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_in_film#Marc_Webb_films_(2012%E2%80%932014))).

(For full 100%-completism, also watch [*Venom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony%27s_Spider-Man_Universe#Venom_(2018)) and its sequel [*Venom: Let There Be Carnage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony%27s_Spider-Man_Universe#Venom:_Let_There_Be_Carnage_(2021)).)